# R groupby and mutate together with lag equivalent in Pyspark

Tags: r, pyspark

I am trying to find the equivalent Pyspark code for the below R Code.

## generate lag variables

```
car <-
  car %>%
  group_by(Model) %>%
  mutate(Target.1 = lag(Target, 3),Sales.1 = lag(Sales, 3))
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Window functions ought to work, though you would need something to order by:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy("Model").orderBy( ??? )
car = car.withColumn("Target.1", func.lag("Target", 3).over(window))\
    .withColumn("Sales.1", func.lag("Sales", 3))
```

Comment: I am using this one in loop. I have 3 rows for each month. I am using the below condition. Some reason, the results not correct.
for i in range(3):
    if i<= 3:
        df = df.withColumn("target1", func.when(df.Month == 1, df.Target).otherwise(func.lag(df.Target,3).over(Window.partitionBy(a,b,c).orderBy(a,b,c))))

Comment: How is it not functioning correctly? And why do you have both "for i in range(3)" and "if i <= 3", this seems redundant.

Comment: The one you helped me working perfectly, my logic was wrong. Thanks for you help :)